# Reading changes done in table and replicate them to another system

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, jax-rs, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have to insert data into Oracle digital assistant(ODA) by calling an API POST method service. I am reading data from an Oracle table where all the transactions happened in a day, and my system needs to be inserted into `ODA`(Consider it as another `database`).

I have created a `trigger` on the main table which will insert all the transaction which happens in a day to another table. Using `jdbc` I will read this table and write the data into `file`. Then I will call the `API` which will inject the data into `ODA`. Once data will be inserted into `ODA` I will truncate the `table` so that next day it `inserts` fresh `data`.

I am writing trigger on main table so any DML operation happened on the `table` needs to be inserted into another `table`. I was also not aware that I had to reflect the changes done by updates or deletes.

After reading all changes I will truncate the replicated table where the changes are located.

Is there any better approach that a trigger DML ?

Comment: hello, are you only inserting on the main table ? or there are also deletes and updates ?

Comment: Thank you @RobertoHernandez for highlighting. there are update and delete as well,

Comment: how big is the main table ??

Comment: Actually main table has around 100,000 record

Comment: This question is more like opinion based question I think which is not allowed in SO

Comment: This question would be easier to answer if you included a [mcve] demonstrating the situation. This question would be easier to read if you didn't use inline code formatting for every third word. (It's only for code. None of the things in your question are code. That's part of the problem.)

Comment: Thank you @CodyGray I will edit the same.

Comment: @ShwetaMishra, I post an alternative. Feel free to comment on the answer.

Comment: Thank you @RobertoHernandez . I am going through the same

Answer (score 1):

I won't use a trigger in this case. What happens if you have deletes or updates in the main table and you use only a trigger for inserts ? In this case, I would use a MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG to get the changes

let me show you how

```
SQL> create table t ( c1 number primary key, c2 number ) ;

Table created.

SQL>  declare
 begin
 for i in 1 .. 100000
 loop
 insert into t values ( i , dbms_random.value ) ;
 end loop;
 commit ;
 end;
 /  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create materialized view log on t with primary key ;

Materialized view log created.

SQL> select count(*) from t ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    100000
```

Now we have a materialized view log which will replicate all changes done in the source table using the primary key

```
SQL> insert into t values ( 100001 , dbms_random.value ) ;

1 row created.

SQL>  select count(*) from t ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
    100001

SQL> select count(*) from mlog$_t ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

Now, during the night you want to reflect only the changes done in the target materialized view

1.First lock the original table to avoid any operation

```
SQL> LOCK TABLE MY_TEST ;
```

2.Changes are in the log mview

```
SQL> select * from t where c1 in ( select c1 from mlog$_t ) ;

       C1         C2
---------- ----------
    10000! .276556329
```

3.Once you got all changes copied to the API , then purge the log

```
SQL> BEGIN
DBMS_SNAPSHOT.PURGE_LOG (
master => 'T',
num => 1,
flag => 'DELETE');
END;
/  2    3    4    5    6    7

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>  select count(*) from mlog$_t ;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0
```

With this you will be sure that all changes are covered.

**In your case, I think you don't even need the materialized view, only the materialized view log**